# Progressbar visibility property not working with data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

> Visibility property not working

```
      <data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
  
    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="com.wiesoftware.spine.ui.auth.LoginViewModel" />
</data>
```

> This is my progressbar code

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbLogin"
        android:visibility="@{viewmodel.isVisibles ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default=gone}"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName" />
```

> I am changing the value of isVisibles in viewModel but it doesn't reflect please give a solution. This is the class where I change isVisibles value.

````
class LoginViewModel(
    private val authRepositry: AuthRepositry
):ViewModel() {
    var email:String?=null
    var password:String?=null
    var loginEventListener:LoginEventListener?=null
    var isVisibles:Boolean=false
    fun loginButtonClicked(view: View){
        isVisibles=true
        if (email.isNullOrEmpty() || password.isNullOrEmpty()){
            loginEventListener?.onLoginFailed("Please enter credentials.")
            isVisibles=false
            return
        }
}
}```

> I have updated viewmodel class please check and let me know where is the issue I am using Kotlin Please provide me solution thanks
````

Comment: post your isVisibles() method

Comment: Did you bind you viewModel to this layout? `binding.viewmodel = myViewModel` for example

Answer (score 0):

try add this

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = this // activity
```